# Array object empty when enumerating but not when accessing by index

Tags: c#, async-await

I have async method when I get the data from web api via HttpClient object.
I print out the response string and I can see that I have the right data.

I also convert the response to the array of my custom class which works just fine (I can log the properties to the console).

When I print the properties by index everything works fine:

```
Debug.WriteLine("B: " + brands[0].Brand);
```

but when I enumerate the array it doesn't log the data, it looks like it contain empty string, why?:

```
foreach (Brand brand in brands)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("BRAND: ", brand.Brand.ToString()); // Prints just BRAND:
}
```

This is how my method looks like:

```
 public static async Task<Brand[]> LoadBrandsAsync()
    {
        Brand[] brands = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("Brands");
            try
            {
                brands = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Brand[]>();
                Debug.WriteLine("Count: " + brands.Count());
                Debug.WriteLine("B: " + brands[0].Brand); // This works fine 
                Debug.WriteLine("B: " + brands[0].Sales); // it print out the data

                foreach (Brand brand in brands)
                {
                    // This does't work, WHY?
                    Debug.WriteLine("BRAND: ", brand.Brand.ToString() + ", " + brand. Sales.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        return brands;
    }
```

Can someone answer why the object in the array looks like empty while enumerating?

Comment: Just a mild pedant:  You're not _enumerating_ the array you are _iterating_ it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument of all `Debug.WriteLine` is format string with element place hoders like: `"BRAND: {0}, {1}..."`, in your case there is no `{0}`, so additional arguments are ignored.

Check out [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) help. You also will not need `.Tostring()` calls - automatically executed if argument is not string and not null:

```
  Debug.WriteLine("BRAND: {0}, {1}", brand.Brand, brand.Sales);
```